# How to represent a 5 digit decimal value as a 24 bit value?

Tags: c#, binary, hex, decimal, bit

I'm trying to convert a 5 digit decimal value (ranging from 00001 to 99999) and somehow represent it as a 24-bit value split into 3 bytes but have tried every conversion and bitshift tactic I know, but keep getting stuck :/

Example: decimal value is 12345, and I need to send 3 hex values [aa][bb][cc], which would consist of:

[aa] - least significant | [bb] - middle | [cc] - most significant

I'm hoping I'm not in over my head and that there is a simple answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is 12345 not 003039 in hex? I feel like I must be issing something here?

Comment: Yeah, but 99999 is 1869F, would that just break out to 01 86 9F?

Comment: Yes, that's how it would be represented in hex.

Comment: Gah... I just realized that my issue was that I was using an int instead of a long... I saw your answer and upon reading it was thinking "well yes, of course that is what would be" but then I realized 003039 wasn't what my program was outputting from an input of 12345. I double checked and it was outputting a blank. I changed int to long for my variables and I started getting actual results *facepalm*.

Comment: Long day, thank you and sorry for the silly question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Decimal number = new Decimal() { number = 12345 };
            string output = number.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class Decimal
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string output = string.Format("[{0}][{1}][{2}]",
                (number & 0xFF).ToString("X2"),
                ((number >> 8) & 0xFF).ToString("X2"),
                ((number >> 16) & 0xFF).ToString("X2"));
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner than how I was doing it, this is very helpful thank you!

Comment: Side note `Decimal` is very bad name for type that stores `Int32`... Unless the goal is to troll :)

Comment: My Decimal starts with a capital D.  I just used nomenclature that OP used.

Comment: _"My Decimal starts with a capital D"_ -- so does `System.Decimal`. _"I just used nomenclature that OP used"_ -- the OP didn't post any code with a type named `Decimal`.

Comment: System.Decimal is a Net library class.  The code above is a user defined class.