# What does it mean to convert an int to a 24-bit value?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I came across the requirement in a project for converting an integer value to a 24-bit value, split into 3 bytes, which is answered in this question:
[How to represent a 5 digit decimal value as a 24 bit value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977551/how-to-represent-a-5-digit-decimal-value-as-a-24-bit-value)

However, I am having a hard time understanding what it fundamentally means to convert an integer to a 24bit value

ie:

```
int number = 12345;
            string output = string.Format("[{0}][{1}][{2}]",
                (number & 0xFF).ToString("X2"),
                ((number >> 8) & 0xFF).ToString("X2"),
                ((number >> 16) & 0xFF).ToString("X2"));
```

Comment: There is some subtlety to this.  Please consider being very specific.   Talking about "integers" is not exactly the same as talking about the particular data type `int`.   These things are of course closely related but the subtle difference is **totally relevant to the question**.  What you are truly asking about is `int`.

Comment: Please show 7 example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Technically, any integer less than `16777216` (unsigned) or `8388608` (signed) _is_ already a 24-bit integer. So _"fundamentally"_, it means _nothing_ to _"convert an integer to a 24bit value"_. On the other hand, per the question you're referencing, clearly they don't really mean a 24-bit value, but rather a sequence of 8-bit values, where the least-significant byte is displayed first. And on the third hand, ...

Comment: ... you _"came across the requirement"_ in some other context, where _"converting a [sic] integer value to a 24 bit value"_ could mean yet something else. We can't tell you what is meant in that context; you need to ask the person who produced the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers can be any arbitrary number of bits, there is also [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and [negative numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to take into account.

Assuming a unsigned 32bit number as input the simplest option would be to simply remove the most significant byte, i.e. 2^25 would be transformed to 0. You might want to clamp the value before converting to avoid this wrap-around behavior.

The simplest way to convert a number to discrete bytes should be [Bitconverter.GetBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0).

Note that 24-bit numbers are kind of a pain to use due to these issues, so I would in most cases recommend using 32 or 16 bit values if possible. The closest real world usage I know of would be 24-bit color images. If size is a concern it is often effective enough to use some form of compression.